# project Euler #23 Python

Tags: python, algorithm

So I am working on Project Euler #23, and I need some efficiency assistance.

Ok so the original problem is:

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

I have gotten most of the code to run efficiently, but the one part I am having trouble with is finding all numbers that are a sum of two abundant numbers.

```
import math
import time
def factors(n):
    fact=[1,n]
    check=2
    rootn=math.sqrt(n)
    while check<rootn:
        if n%check==0:
                fact.append(check)
                fact.append(n/check)
        check+=1
    if rootn==check:
        fact.append(check)
    fact.sort()
    return fact

abundantNumbers = []
timeStart = time.time()
for i in range(12, 28124):
    factorTemp = factors(i)
    totalTemp = 0
    factorTemp.remove(i)
    for j in range(len(factorTemp)):
        factorTemp[j] = float(factorTemp[j])
    for j in range(len(factorTemp)):
        totalTemp+=factorTemp[j]
        if totalTemp> i:
            abundantNumbers.append(i)
            break
nums = []
doubleAbu = []
for i in range(24, 28124):
    nums.append(i)

for j in abundantNumbers:
    if j*2 < 28123 and j*2 not in doubleAbu:
        doubleAbu.append(j*2)
      
for i in abundantNumbers:
    repeat=True
    for j in abundantNumbers[abundantNumbers.index(i):]:
        if i + j not in doubleAbu and i + j <28123:
            doubleAbu.append(i+j)
        elif i + j > 28123:
            break
            repeat = False
    if not repeat:
        break
total = 0
for i in range(len(doubleAbu)):
    nums.remove(doubleAbu[i])
for i in range(len(nums)):
    total += nums[i]
         

print("It took, ", str(time.time()-timeStart), " seconds!")
#print((abundantNumbers))
print(doubleAbu)
print(total)
```

I have done a fair share of research, and I am certain there are thousands of ways of doing it better than I have, but if anybody has any equations or just a better way to find positive integers that are the sum of two abundant numbers I could use some help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you feel it is necessary to (1) sort the factors or (2) convert them to floating point?

Comment: @rici I made the factoring code a very long time ago, but I do see how that is unnecessary, and I convert it to a float because often times I was getting an error that said I cannot compare a float and an integer so i figured easier make it all into floats

Comment: As far as I know, there is no circumstance in Python where it is not permitted to compare floats and integers. You can't compare a float with a `Decimal` but that's quite a different kettle of fish. Also: use the `sum` function. It's a lot faster than writing out the loop. (Testing the incremental sum and terminating early is a false optimization. The test at least doubles the computation cost, and you never find abundancy half way through the sum -- you would need to add from highest to lowest to have a chance, and even then most numbers aren't abundant.)...

Comment: For the double loop over the abundant numbers, iterate indices, not values; the call to `find` is too slow to be useful. And record the result in a `set` rather than a list, to save having to check manually for duplicates, another massive inefficiency. (You could use a boolean array as niemmi suggests, but the `set` is cooler and more flexible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a list of 28124 boolean values initialized to `False`. Then iterate over the abundant numbers and for each number find the all sums with numbers equal or greater than it. For every sum x set the xth flag in the list `True`. Since the abundant numbers are in ascending order you can break the inner loop when sum is greater than 28123. Then in the final step iterate over the list and sum together all the indeces which have `False` value:

```
import math
import time
def factors(n):
    fact=[1,n]
    check=2
    rootn=math.sqrt(n)
    while check<rootn:
        if n%check==0:
                fact.append(check)
                fact.append(n//check)
        check+=1
    if rootn==check:
        fact.append(check)
    fact.sort()
    return fact

abundantNumbers = []
timeStart = time.time()
for i in range(12, 28124):
    factorTemp = factors(i)
    totalTemp = 0
    factorTemp.remove(i)
    for j in range(len(factorTemp)):
        factorTemp[j] = float(factorTemp[j])
    for j in range(len(factorTemp)):
        totalTemp+=factorTemp[j]
        if totalTemp> i:
            abundantNumbers.append(i)
            break

MAX = 28123
result = [False] * (MAX + 1)

for i in range(len(abundantNumbers)):
    for j in range(i, len(abundantNumbers)):
        s = abundantNumbers[i] + abundantNumbers[j]
        if s > MAX:
            break
        result[s] = True

print(sum(i for i, x in enumerate(result) if not x))
print("It took, ", str(time.time()-timeStart), " seconds!")
```

Output:

```
4179871
It took,  3.190303325653076  seconds!
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster and shorter version, although I am pretty sure it can still be improved.

```
import time
from math import ceil

# Sum of Proper Divisors of
def sopd(n):
    if n == 1: return 0
    s = 1
    sqrt = ceil(n ** 0.5)
    for b in range(2, sqrt):
        if n % b == 0:
            s += (b + n // b)
    return s + (sqrt if sqrt ** 2 == n else 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    abundant = set()
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,28124):
        if not any(i-a in abundant for a in abundant):
            s += i
        if sopd(i) > i:
            abundant.add(i)
    print(s)
    print("--- {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

It takes about 1.2 seconds on my pc